# Swift добавить элемент в словарь, а если уже существует, то увеличить

Tags: swift, dict, словарь

Не могу нигде найти пример как добавить элемент в словарь, а если он уже существует, то увеличить.

Например у меня есть пустой словарь:

```
var emptyDict: [String:Int] = [:]
```

И я хочу добавить туда элемент

```
["test": 1]
```

Если уже такой элемент есть в словаре, то он должен увеличится на 1, а если нет - создать с таким же значением

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=Swift+add+item+to+dict+site:stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwitvunP6eHjAhVEposKHXQTCiMQrQIoBDAAegQIBRAO&biw=1463&bih=740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем проблема-то? Достаточно простого ифа:

```
if let num = dict[str] {
    dict[str]=num+1
} else {
    dict[str]=1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у Вас объявлен подобный массив строк:

```
var strings = ["test", "test1", "test2", "test", "test", "test2", "test1"]
```

Возможно, в ходе работы приложения Вы его модифицируете. На основе значений `strings` Вам нужно заполнить `emptyDict`. В Swift 5/Xcode 10.3 Вы можете воспользоваться `Dictionary.subscript(_:default:)` для выполнения данной задачи:

```
strings.forEach {
    emptyDict[$0, default: 0] += 1
}
print(emptyDict) // Выведет в консоль ["test2": 2, "test1": 2, "test": 3]
```

Если `strings` является константой, то Вы также можете проинициализировать `emptyDict` с помощью `Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`:

```
let emptyDict = Dictionary(grouping: strings) { $0 }.mapValues { $0.count }
```